# Can not deactivate Alt+F7 XWindows shortcut (conflict with Netbeans)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager

As a developer I want to use the Netbeans IDE Shortcuts in elementar OS 0.4. But I can not deactivate XWindow shortcuts that conflict with Netbeans' shortcut. Example: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

It is not listed in `Settings - Keyboard - Shortcuts - Windows`...

Answer (score 10):

Let's do it from `gsettings`:

**`gsettings list-recursively | grep \<Alt\>F7`**

This finds all actions set to that keybinding. For instance, mine:

```
org.gnome.mutter.wayland.keybindings switch-to-session-7 ['<Primary><Alt>F7']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-move ['<Alt>F7']
```

Set any conflicts to blank ('') or another keybinding. For example,

**`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-move "['']"`**

Voilà! And if you ever want to restore the default, use this format:
**`gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-move`**

Comment: This worked for me. I think that these keybindings should appear in Keyboard Settings as the OP mentioned. I use this shortcut in IntelliJ often.